# Spring Boot - Failed to complete processing of a request java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, spring-boot, post

After an update of the java dependencies, I'm facing a OutOfMemoryError when I upload more than 1 file via post.
The project is a simple Java SpringBoot server, I need to send CSV files (~10/15 MB).
The error of the server is:

```
ERROR [serialparts-tecdoc-service,,,] 43717 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to complete processing of a request

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:361) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.<init>(Http11OutputBuffer.java:110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.<init>(Http11Processor.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.createProcessor(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:1089) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:878) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar:9.0.44]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

This is the list of dependency of my project:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20200518</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I did not change the code, but I've updated the dependencies.
I want to tell you that the error is not after a lot of time, but during the first file that I upload.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: you can configure the Heap size of your program if it is necessary

Comment: Have you tried giving more memory to the Java program?

Comment: In addition to my comment above, check if you have any memory leaks

Comment: Yes, I tried, the problem is that the error is when I read my first file. not after hours.

Comment: Hi, do you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact stack trace when the `server.max-http-header-size` property was set too high. If it's a significant fraction of your heap size, you will very quickly get an OutOfMemoryError. Did you set this property? Can you reduce it to something closer to the default 8KB?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check for memory leaks as [here](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/j-leaks/)

Another option is to give your program a bigger heap memory size

of the JVM, use the maven-surefire-plugin

```
<configuration>
  <argLine> -Xmx1024m </argLine>
</configuration>
```

But I say it again, check your application for memory leaks.

And try this if your program needs more memory. Good luck :)

Comment: Hi, I think that the error is not a memory leak. I have this error when I send my first file to the server, not after hours. I disabled the body of the method to avoid problems about memory issues of secondari parts. I can confirm that the error is in spring.